# finding an automatically fill empty cells in a column with a corresponding row from another column in sheets/app script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

not experienced enough with Apps Script but I am with python and basically, given 2 similar column with different lengths, I'm trying to fill in the missing rows with the rows from the longer column. For python my intuition would be to loop through the longer column and if the cell does not match the corresponding cell on the short column i just add that missing cell. Final result would be the shorter column be filled with the missing cells/rows so that it's now the same length of the original. If this could be done with a formula instead that would be fine too. I considered VLOOKUP and INDEX MATCH functions to add the cells but I don't want to override the entire row since it has data that is valuable, otherwise this would just be a simple copy and paste. Here's an example:

| ID | col 1 | col 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A |
| 2 | B | B |
| 3 | C | E |
| 4 | D |  |
| 5 | E |  |

my target would be to make col 2 be just like col 1, move down row 3 in col2 to row 5 and add rows 3 and 4 from col 1 into 2, so to find a way in Apps Script to say:

```
if len(col 1) > len (col 2):
  for i in len(col 1):
    if col 1[i] != col 2[i]:
      col 2[i] == col 1[i]
```

that's the main concept at least. I know there is an insert function or something better to sue even in python. it's just an idea floating in my head and I can't figure out executing it just yet.

Comment: Why not just delete Col2 and copy/paste Col1?

Comment: Would the data, say Col 1, ID 1, "A" be the same as Col 2, ID 1, "A", or would there be a different value in Col 2, ID 1?

Comment: Also, is the main language that you are looking to use for this Python or JS? Or does it matter?

Comment: the reason i can't copy and paste col 1 into 2 is because practically they are in 2 different sheets and spanning multiple columns, so some of the rows attributed to column 2 in other sheets would be populated with data I cannot override. Sorry, should've mentioned this earlier

The data would be different, I only need to add the missing data in 1 into 2. 
I'm trying to do this using appscript (which is using JS i'm being told). Worst case I'd have to use python but I really don't want to for this project.

Comment: Start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets. If you need further help, please add a [mcve] showing what you have tried to create the script in Google Apps Script. Please be specific about if you will be using a bounded project (create the script form the Google Sheets menu) or if you will be working with a standalone script (usually created from https://script.google.com or from Google Drive)

Comment: Whatever you've said changes things a lot.  See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for official documentation, free resources, **Best practices** and more details.

Comment: Gotcha @Oak, I would follow Ruben's comment, I only know python and wouldn't be able to help you with the app script part anyways. Hope you can find a solution.

Comment: Thank you all! I will follow the Google guide and if I get stuck again I promise I will do a better job explaining and presenting. Thank you again!